# How to compress images without losing the original file?

Tags: java, android, file, image-compression

I'm using this code for image compression before uploading the images :

```
public File saveBitmapToFile(File file) {
    try {

        // BitmapFactory options to downsize the image
        BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        o.inSampleSize = 6;
        // factor of downsizing the image

        FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
        //Bitmap selectedBitmap = null;
        BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream, null, o);
        inputStream.close();

        // The new size we want to scale to
        final int REQUIRED_SIZE = 75;

        // Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
        int scale = 1;
        while (o.outWidth / scale / 2 >= REQUIRED_SIZE &&
                o.outHeight / scale / 2 >= REQUIRED_SIZE) {
            scale *= 2;
        }

        BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o2.inSampleSize = scale;
        inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);

        Bitmap selectedBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream, null, o2);
        inputStream.close();


        FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);


        selectedBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, outputStream);



        return file;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

The problem is the original image will be affected and get resized.

How to compress images without overwriting and losing the original one?

**Update 1 :**

I changed the last part of the code to this but still doesn't work.

now the image wouldn't get resized

```
            File new_file =new File("/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Screenshots/tmp.png");
        try
        {
            new_file.createNewFile();
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Log.d("Create File", "File exists?"+new_file.exists());

        FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(new_file);

        selectedBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, outputStream);


        return file;
```

**Update 2 :**

I've changed the code to this so the problem is partly solved. Now I can have an original quality of each image in a file named `tmp"+new Date()+".png` but the original file still will be overwritten.

```
File new_file =new File(String.valueOf("/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Screenshots/tmp"+new Date()+".png"));
        try
        {
            new_file.createNewFile();
            FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(new_file, true);
            selectedBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, outputStream);


        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Log.d("Create File", "File exists?"+new_file.exists());

        FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);

        selectedBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, outputStream);
```

Comment: What does not work about it?

Comment: @MattClark I added update 2 to the question

Answer (score 0):

Create a new File and make the FileOutputStream write to it, rather than writing to the original.

Comment: Why are you compressing twice?  The second one is still using the original file, so its overwriting it.

Comment: I did it like this : The `new_file` would have the original  content and the original file will be overwritten

Answer (score 0):

**New Answer**

Your case is quite unique, what if you try this:

Rather than directly using the Bitmap from InputStream, try use it's `copy()`.

That way, the one that you compress will be the copy of the Bitmap. And you can compress that in your new `FileOutputStream` without modifying the original file.

And remove the second compression. Just dont do anything with your original file.

Comment: I did it like this : The `new_file` would have the original  content and the original file will be overwritten

Comment: Try to see my new answer. And hope it works this time.